# Feedback for string exercises in OpenOlat with R/exams

Tags: r, r-exams, openolat

I have the following problem. I want to export this exercise written with R/exams to OpenOLAT

````
```{r, include=FALSE}
explanation <- "Long Text"
solution <- "Short Text"
```

Question
========
Question


Solution
========
`r explanation`


META-INFORMATION
=================
extype: string
exsolution: `r solution`
````

When I export this exercise to OpenOlat with the `exams2openolat()` function, the long explanation given in the section "Solution" is not displayed in the result feedback given by OpenOlat after finishing the test, only the short answer from `solution`. How can I fix this? I want my students to have a look at the longer explanation too.

I tried to fix this via the test configurations in OpenOlat. I activated all options in the section "Report" and in the "Options" section I activated "Show feedback". However, it still does not show the long explanation in the results.

Comment: Did the response below answer your question? If so, please accept it (by clicking the check mark on the left) so that the question is flagged correspondingly here on SO. If not, please clarify the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The long solution section is only shown if an incorrect answer is entered by the participant (and if `solutionswitch = TRUE`, the default).

This is shown immediately during the quiz. As far as I know it is not possible to enable this solution feedback on the report at the end.

Comment: Dear Achim, too bad, but thank you very much for your response! :)

Comment: I will raise this issue again with our e-learning team. Maybe there are some OpenOlat capabilities I'm not aware of...

Comment: That would be great, thank you very much! :)